# html5 video in chrome only plays with autoplay?

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

I've got the following code for a HTML5 video, which works fine in all browsers except Chrome:

```
<video id="video-03" preload controls poster="/images/videos/testing.jpg" width="480" height="854">
   <source src="/images/videos/testing.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="/images/videos/testing.webm" type="video/webm">
   <source src="/images/videos/testing.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

I **don't** want autoplay turned on.

The only way I can get this to work in Chrome, is if autoplay is turned on, but still no controls to stop/start it show.

Any ideas why Chrome isn't showing the controls? Even if I right click on the video it has a tick next to "Show Controls". So Chrome thinks they're displaying, but there's nothing there.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed? Extensions might mess with it. If not try it in incognito mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you stuck ? 
look this below code it shows all controls, maybe you have another problem in your System.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The video tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```